# Does Excel Automation in UI Path support libre Office csv files

Tags: uipath, excel-automation

I'm trying to read contents from CSV files in UiPath. While trying to execute the workflow I'm getting the following error. But I've already installed the libre office on my PC.

[image: Error that I'm getting]

Comment: You basically answered your own question. Excel automation either requires you to have Excel installed, or usage of the Office Open XML Format (XSLX).  You might want to rephrase this.

Answer (score 0):

UiPath can read excel or csv files without the help of any other software. You can use 'read csv' activity for this case.

[image]

And the error that you showed looks user defined.